# UITableViewCell not always selectable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm in the middle of trying to debug an issue with a new app, and something isn't right.  In the app, I'm setting up custom UITableViewCells by adding 2 UILabels and 1 UIImageView directly to the cell.contentView

In my app, certain table view cells werent selectable ( they werent responding to tap events ).  The 2nd cell on the screen was always never selectable, and then random other cells also werent selectable.

In my effort to debug, I stripped everything down the following bare essentials of code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ReviewCell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
  }
  cell.textLabel.text = @"foo";
  return cell;
}
```

Even this is generic, boiler plate code, that looks like the following:

[image]

not all the cells are selectable.

What am I missing?

**update**

as an updated here is my row selection code if interested

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ReviewWebViewController *rvc = [[ReviewWebViewController alloc] initWithReview:[self.reviews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvc animated:YES];
    [rvc release], rvc=nil;
}
```

Comment: and presumably, you are not returning nil from a tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: method or anything?

Comment: What action you are doing in *didSelectRowAtIndexPath:* method?

Comment: here is my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:


 ReviewWebViewController *rvc = [[ReviewWebViewController alloc] initWithReview:[self.reviews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvc animated:YES];
 [rvc release], rvc=nil;

Comment: @Brynjar - no i dont even have the willSelectRow delegate method in my controller

Comment: Just in case... Are you sure your code is in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and not `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:`? I've done it once because I selected the wrong method in the autocompletion list...

Comment: @Jilouc

yes, it is the didSelect method not didDeselect.  for info purposes, I've pasted that method as an update  on my original post if you are curious.

Comment: Did you try to put an `NSLog` statement into `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to see if there is a problem with that method? Do you at least see the highlighting when trying to select a non-selectable cell? By the way, in your very last line of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, you should replace the comma with a semicolon.

Comment: @Bjorn,

No the cell isnt highlighting when the selection doesnt work. It only shows the highlight state when its selected.  What would I log for?  The method isnt being called at all on tap, so the log would never trigger

Also, a comma vs semicolon doesnt matter in this case.  Its a common use-pattern to release and set to nil on the same instruction via a comma

Comment: What about adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to each cell to see if the touch is detected at all?

Comment: @Bjorn, worth a shot.  I'll try that out and see if its detecting taps.  You are, of course, suggesting adding it to the cell itself, and not the cell.contentView's individual contents?

Comment: @cpjolicoeur: Yes, directly to the cell. I already used a UISwipeGestureRecognizer in one of my projects to display an overlay view sliding in from the left. Worked perfectly when adding it to the cell, no matter where the swipe began or ended.

Comment: @Bjorn,

I added the UITapGestureRecognizer to the cell.  The cell isnt receiving the tap recognizer when I'm tapping on the items added to the cell.contentView.  The only time it fires is if i click on the extremeties of the cell or on the disclosure indicator section

certain cells will register the tap fine, others wont

Comment: Which cells are selectable vs. not. Is it consistent? Is it actually random? If it is, I wonder if you are getting hit by a memory issue. Maybe try getting rid of that autorelease.

Comment: @Hack Saw,

I can't find any consistent pattern, so I think its random.  The only consistent thing I can find is that the 2nd table cell always seems to be unclickable.  The first cell is unclickable probably 50% of the time, and then the rest change randomly

Comment: There is nothing in your examples that would explain why your cell is not selectable. What does the frame look like on that table?

Comment: @WrightsCS

not sure what you are asking.  I havent manipulated the view.frame in anyway, but let me know what kind of specific info you need.

Comment: is the controller a UIViewController with a tableView? or a UITableViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your view hierarchy look like? Two things come to mind: either there are other views besides the table view that could be intercepting the touch events, or the table view itself is outside of its superviews frame (and clipping is turned off).

Long story short - lot of suggestions focusing on the implementation of the table view itself, I'd take a look at everything around it.

Comment: It is just a basic UITableViewController.  Nothing special in the view heirarchy.

I do create a UIView and add some elements to it that I then later set as the tableHeaderView via "self.tableView.tableHeaderView = myHeaderView"

Comment: and how is the UITableViewController being added to the hierarchy?

Comment: In the end, I had a loading HUD that was intercepting click events.  Instead of removing the HUD from the superview when it was done animating, I was simply stopping the animation but leaving the HUD in place

Answer (score 4):

A lot of things have been mentioned, which I will not re-iterate.

But make sure that the elements you add to the UITableViewCell have their `userInteractionEnabled` set to `NO`. Especially when not using IB, never make too many assumptions about defaults.

Answer (score 2):

I got hit by a similar sounding bug a few weeks ago. I had buttons in a scroll view that weren't responding to touches. It turned out to be an invisible `UILabel` that I left in my IB file, never filled with text and forgot about. It was sitting over the buttons and intercepting their touches.

The way I found it was to loop through all the subviews of the scroll view, turning the background color of each view yellow. Could you have a stray view which is interfering with touches?

You could also try sizing the labels and images in your cell to something tiny (10x10) to see if they are interfering.
As a last resort, you could start with fresh code and add back in parts to see where it breaks.

One last point: You say that you're using a custom `UITableViewCell`, but you initialize the cell with the default type:

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                               reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

Shouldn't you be using your custom cell here? Is that just to simplify the example?

Comment: sorry, a bit more explanation.  I not using IB at all here, so I dont think I would have any UILabels that I cant see, but I will try your suggestion on coloring them all and see if I missed something.

by "custom" UITableViewCell I mean that I am adding my elements directly to the cell.contentView directly, and not using the predefined cell.textView.text and cell.detailedTextView.text elements that are present by default.  I'm manually adding two UILabels and one UIImageView to the cell.contentView myself manually.

Comment: to check, I did remove all my custom code and used what I pasted above and only set the cell.textLabel.text = @"foo" and I still cant get consistent clicks

Comment: neven, as an update, I went ahead and did a "for (UIView *v in cell.subviews)" and set them all to have a [UIColor yellowColor] as the background color.  I also manually set the 3 fields I'm adding with red, green, and blue background colors.  Here is a link to a screencap to illustrate what is happening.  The first two cells aren't receiving taps at all except directly on the disclosure indicator (in white).  The third cell I can click anywhere int he cell and the tap is registered fine.

http://cl.ly/3q1c453t1D1r3h3B1D11

Answer (score 1):

I tried with a sample application, which entirely mimicked your approach. It all worked absolutely fine. I wonder why your code doesn't work when every single bit of code mentioned above is correct. If required I can share my code with you. I am using the following code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"Row Tapped At %d",indexPath.row);
    NextViewController *rvc = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithReview:[self.reviews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvc animated:YES];
    [rvc release], rvc=nil;

}
```

where 
     Review *first = [[[Review alloc] initWithReviewId:1 andTitle:@"First"] autorelease]; and so on...
self.reviews = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen,fourteen,fifteen,sizteen,nil];

I am using iPhone SDK 4.2.Please let me know If this mimics your approach and correct me If I have made any mistake.
Thanks

Comment: Rahul

Thanks for taking the time to do all that.  I also, have created completely new projects in xcode from scratch trying to debug this, and I'm not seeing the same issues in blank projects, just this one. I'd like to figure out why this one isnt working, even with the minimum amount of code (that is clearly correct) doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

If Nevan's solution doesn't help, then try removing the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath method (or commenting it out) and see if the buttons glow with the blue hightlight when tapped. If they do, then I would suspect that

```
ReviewWebViewController *rvc = [[ReviewWebViewController alloc] initWithReview:[self.reviews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Is not always returning an object. To confirm this, set a breakpoint on the following line and check that rvc is not null. If it is, then that's the issue.

Comment: I have commented out the method as a test before.  The issue isnt that rvc isnt being set.  The didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is not even being called at all on taps for some cells, so there is nothing to debug in that method.  When taps are detected, things work as expected and rvc is set fine, however this method is usually not even triggered on taps (unless I tap the disclosure indicator directly)

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you take out the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: codepath, and always use a fresh cell - are they all selectable then?

Is there a parent view to the UITableViewController whose frame could be set smaller than the bounds of the tableView?  If so, touches outside the bounds of this parent will not register in the tableView.  You'd still see the full tableView as long as the parent's clipSubviews was NO.

Also, check to see that your app window has "wants full screen at launch" set in the nib.  If not, then the window may be the wrong size and touch events may not be reaching your tableview.